# first common ancestor of two nodes in a binary tree

Tags: java, binary-tree, ancestor

I was trying to solve the problem 4.7 from the book cracking the code interview (very cool book!).

> Design an algorithm and write code to find the first common ancestor
>   of two nodes in a binary tree. Avoid storing additional nodes in a
>   data structure. NOTE: This is not necessarily a binary search tree.

And I came up with this solution which is not even close to the ones provided in the book. I wonder if someone can find any flaws on it?

Solution:
I created a wraper class to hold the first common ancestor (if its found) and 2 booleans to track if a or b was found when recoursively searching the tree. Please read added comments in the code below.

```
public static void main (String args[]){
    NodeTree a, b, head, result; //initialise and fill with data
    fillTreeTestData(head);
    pickRandomNode(a);
    pickRandomNode(b);
    result = commonAnsestor(a,b,head);
    if(result != null)
        System.out.println("First common ansestor "+result);
    else
        System.out.println("Not found");

}

class TreeNode{
    Object value;
    TreeNode right, left;
}

class WraperNodeTree{
    boolean found_a;
    boolean found_b;
    NodeTree n;

    WraperNodeTree (boolean a, boolean b, NodeTree n){
        this.n = n;
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}

static WraperNodeTree commonAnsestor(NodeTree a, NodeTree b, NodeTree current){
    // Let's prepare a wraper object
    WraperNodeTree wraper = new WraperNodeTree(false, false, null);
    // we reached the end
    if(current == null) return wraper;

    // let's check if current node is either a or b
    if(a != null)
        wraper.found_a = current.value.equals(a.value);
    else if(b != null)
        wraper.found_b = current.value.equals(b.value);
    else
        return wraper; // if both are null we don't need to keep searching recoursively

    // if either a or b was found let's stop searching for it for performance
    NodeTree to_search_a = wraper.found_a ? null : a;
    NodeTree to_search_b = wraper.found_b ? null : b;

    // let's search the left
    WraperNodeTree wraperLeft  = common(to_search_a,to_search_b,current.left);
    // if we already have a common ancester just pass it back recoursively
    if(wraperLeft.n != null) return wraperLeft;

    WraperNodeTree wraperRight = common(to_search_a,to_search_b,current.right);
    if(wraperRight.n != null)return wraperRight;

    // keep the wraper up to date with what we found so far
    wraper.a = wraper.found_a || wraperLeft.found_a || wraperRight.found_a;
    wraper.b = wraper.found_b || wraperLeft.found_b || wraperRight.found_b;

    // if both a and b were found, let's pass the current node as solution
    if(wraper.found_a && wraper.found_b)
        wraper.n = current;

    return wraper;
}
```

Comment: Well, you leave us to imagine what is in the `common` method.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do (some comments would help), but my gut says it doesn't work.  It might help if we knew how you initialize `current`.

Comment: more comments as requested, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If it's about finding flaws:

**Flaw #1:**
I think there are too many typos in your code, which may confuse the interviewer on their first read of the code (and you don't want that!). For example, you write 'NodeTree' and 'TreeNode' interchangeably. Also, you define 'commonAncestor()' and then call 'common()'. Those things make the interviewer confused and make him drift apart from the important thing, which is understanding your way of solving the problem.

**Flaw #2:** Typos aside, I think another flaw is that this code is difficult to follow. I think one of the reasons is because you have 'return' statements all over the body of your function (at the beginning, at the middle and at the end). This should 'normally' be avoided in favor of readability.

Usually my approach is to organize the code in the following way:

1. Basic border case checks (which might include return)
2. Main body of the function (which should NOT return under any conditions)
3. Last checks and final RETURN

But when you have return statements in the middle, it makes it harder for the reader to imagine the flow.

**Flaw #3**: I think you're trying to solve two problems with the same function (commonAncestor). You are trying to both search for 'a' and 'b' and also keeping track of the common ancestor. I think if this is an interview question, you could separate those two objectives in favor of simplicity.

For example, consider this code (might not be perfect and need some extra border checks):

```
/**
 * [Assumption]: If we call firstCommonAncestor(a, b, root)
 * we TRUST that root contains both a and b.
 *
 * You can (and should) discuss this
 * assumption with your interviewer.
 */
public static Node firstCommonAncestor(Node a, Node b, Node root) {
  // If root matches any of the nodes (a or b),
  // then root is the first common ancestor
  // (because of our assumption)
  if(root == a || root == b) return root;

  // Search for a and b in both sides
  SearchResult leftResult = searchNodes(a, b, root.left);
  SearchResult rightResult = searchNodes(a, b, root.right);

  // If a and b are on the same side (left or right), then we
  // call firstCommonAncestor on that side and that’s it
  if(leftResult.aFound && leftResult.bFound)
    return firstCommonAncestor(a, b, root.left);
  else if(rightResult.aFound && rightResult.bFound)
    return firstCommonAncestor(a, b, root.right);
  else {
    // If a and b are in different sides,
    // then we just found the first common ancestor
    return root;
  }
}

class SearchResult {
    boolean aFound, bFound;
}
```

On the code above, I'm separating the task of actually searching for 'a' and 'b' in a different function called searchNodes, which is fairly easy to implement if your interviewer asks for it. But he might not even do that. And if he does, at that point he already understood your approach, so it's easier now to "make the code a bit more complicated" without confusing the interviewer.

I hope this helps.

Comment: My solution was overcomplcated because I failed to do one very important assumption: the first time you find a one one side and b on the other side, you found the first common ansestor.